# Detecting QGIS file lock

Tags: qgis, r

I tried using `rgdal::writeOGR` in R to overwrite a SHP file that was open in QGIS.

```
Error in writeOGR(x, "C:/myFiles", "testFile", : 
   Creation of output file failed
```

Not only did it fail to overwrite the file, but it also deleted all the following auxiliary files:

```
testFile.cpg
testFile.prj
testFile.shx
testFile.sbx
```

Basically everything except the `dbf` and `shp` files. This seems to be standard behavior, and happens every time that I have a file open in QGIS. This also happens whether or not the file is being edited in QGIS.

I'm aware that it's possible to regenerate some of these to save the file, but I'd prefer to avoid this problem altogether by catching a QGIS file lock.

Is there any way (in Python, R or any other) to detect that QGIS has locked a file BEFORE trying to overwrite it? My operating system is Windows 10.

Comment: What operating system? Is this reproducible, or did it happen once? What are the steps that did this? Was the file opened for editing in QGIS? (also, SHXs can be regenerated from the SHP so its not fatal on the Shapefile).

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding regenerating SHX files. I'll update the original question with more details